# Create custom Eclipse editor for only one project type

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

While browsing through the plugin "engine" of Eclipse I was wondering if it is possible to create a custom editor (implementation of EditorPart) which is used for all files of an extension but only if they are within a custom type of project? Let me explain my use case:

I use XML files for UI development together with some scripting language. Now I would like to make a plugin that offers realtime rendering of the current XML in the editor and some kind of WYSIWYG editing behavior. But of course this should only happen if the project is one of my custom project types that has these files. Browsing through the documentation I only found ways to restrict it to file extensions but not file extensions within a project. Is there a way to do so?

Best regards and thanks for any help! Cromon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't restrict an editors use to a particular project.

You can bind your editor to a Content Type. You can then use a `IContentDescriber` to examine a particular file and determine if it is valid for the content type. So if you can identify your XML files from their content only you can do what you want.

There is already a `XMLContentDescriber` class that provides core code for examining XML files.

Comment: Thanks, that does it for me. I can distinctly identify the elements by validating them against my schema definition and if it matches it can use the view.